# Troubleshooting Kelvin's Water Dropper

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, home-experiment, induction

I am attempting to replicate Lord Kelvin's Water Dropper and cannot seem to get it to generate a voltage.  I am not concerned about the spark right now. However, when I fill up the reservoir with water, the stream of water that flows through the inductors and into the collectors is not deflected.  This suggests that there is no charge build up in the collectors and thus no charge build up in the inductors resulting in no deflection of stream.  I have tried all the methods described in [this instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB-76NdfTbU).

Additional info:

- My collectors (cans) had an insulating layer inside and thus charge
  could not be transferred form can collectors to aluminum inductors. I
  used aluminium foil to fix this problem. Does that pose a problem?  I also scraped the insulation just in case.
- I electrically insulated by collectors using two polystyrene plates. The objects in those plates are only to stop the plates from tipping when the cans fill with water.
- Using a multimeter I am 100% sure that the inductions are only connected to the collectors across from them. The wood is also kept bone dry and so does not conduct any charge.

P.S. please ignore the edits on the photos, I pulled them off my Facebook messenger app.

[image: Experimental Setup]
[image: Close up of Inductor]
[image: Removing insulating coating]
[image: Bypassing insulating coating found inside the can]

[image: Close up of Collector]

Comment: The coating needs to be scraped off the can to allow the water to maintain contact. Your scratches seem to be at the top of the can not the bottom in the photo.

Comment: They are at the bottom the lighting is just bad

Comment: Your inductors are tin foil loops. It's crucial to get the drop separation to occur as it falls through the inductors. As yours are not very tall it's difficult.

Comment: There needs to be an intial charge asymmetry to get going. You could cheat this with a battery just initially to get some results.

Comment: The streams will only deflect if they are nearer one side of the inductor than the other. The video didn't say this effect was visible - not sure it is.

Comment: http://www.aluminumfoils.com/converting-materials/coatings.html
Maybe check contacts with a circuit tester, just in case? Oh -you did already.

Comment: JMLCarter concerning your battery idea, do i just connect the positive and negative leads to one collector?

Comment: Easiest thing might be to connect the batter across the spark gap. Then remove it and run the water.

Comment: ohhh thanks. Also would it be a good idea to use salty water instead of plain tap water  in order to increase the amount of charges.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so... You could use bigger collectors and run the water for longer. You could put a voltmeter between the collectors to detect the build up of charge rather than waiting for enough to build up to achieve a spark.

Comment: If the water flow is set such that it breaks into droplets in the vicinity of the rings, the drops may be attracted to the rings enough to touch the rings and deposit their charge on the oppositely charged rings, which decreases the charge on that side of the system.

Comment: Did you get this going? How well does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Can't put a picture in comments, but in terms of collector size, look at this...
[image]